# Is it possible to compare ARM and x86 performance via benchmarks?

Tags: cpu, benchmarking, cpu-architecture

Judging by the latest news, new Apple processor A11 Bionic gains more points than the mobile Intel Core i7 in the Geekbench benchmark.

As I understand, there are a lot of different tests in this benchmark. These tests simulate a different load, including the load, which can occur in everyday use.

Some people state that these results can not be compared to x86 results. They say that x86 is able to perform "more complex tasks". As an example, they lead Photoshop, video conversion, scientific calculations. I agree that the software for the ARM is often only a "lighweight" version of software for desktops. But it seems to me that this limitation is caused by the format of mobile operating systems (do your work on the go, no mouse, etc), and not by the performance of ARM.

As an opposite example, let's look at Safari. A browser is a complex program. And on the iPad Safari works just as well as on the Mac. Moreover, if we take the results of Sunspider (JS benchmark), it turns out that Safari on the iPad is gaining more points.

I think that in everyday tasks (Web, Office, Music/Films) ARM (A10X, A11) and x86 (dual core mobile Intel i7) performance are comparable and equal.

Are there any kinds of tasks where ARM really lags far behind x86? If so, what is the reason for this? What's stopping Apple from releasing a laptop on ARM? They already do same thing with migration from POWER to x86. This is technical restrictions, or just marketing?

Comment: It's because they support different instruction sets, it wouldn't be an apples to apples comparison

Comment: @jmercouris But you can still compare the calories you will have if you eat apples and melons.

Comment: @lilezek yes, but it's more like an apples vs deep fried mars bars comparison, not like one healthy fruit vs another healthy fruit.

Comment: I think you have come to the wrong place with your question.

Comment: I haven't found detailed performance info, just some benchmark results.  [A11 Bionic has 2 "fast" cores, 4 low-power cores](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2017/09/13/geekbench-apple-a11-bionic/), vs. the Intel CPUs people are comparing against only having 2 hyper-threaded cores.  I'm impressed that A11 comes so close to a 3.5GHz Skylake (or whatever is in the top-end 13-inch MacBook Pro) in single-threaded geekbench.

Comment: I'd be surprised if an A11 could keep up with a Skylake / Kaby Lake laptop CPU in high-quality video encoding (x264 / x265 `-preset slower`).  Skylake has very high throughput for 256-bit SIMD vectors, but ARM NEON still only has 128-bit vectors.  (Also, more effort has probably gone into hand-optimizing the asm for x86 AVX2 than for ARM, so that's another reason it's hard to compare what the CPUs are really capable of).  You'd get an even more lop-sided comparison looking at floating-point math throughput (numerical simulations with matrix multiplies).  Intel has *very* high FMA throughput.

Comment: Obviously most of these things aren't relevant workloads for a tablet or phone, but I'm just answering what you literally asked.  There's no technical reason you couldn't design a very high performance ARM CPU; it's a good ISA (and presumably could be extended with something comparable to AVX512).  The problem is economic / market factors, because you'd probably have to redesign a *lot* of the microarchitecture for much higher clocks, wider out-of-order execution, etc. to make a monster ARM.  (Intel's laptop chips use the same cores as their destkop/server CPUs).

Answer (score 3):

(Intended this as a comment since this question is off topic, but it got long..).
Of course you can compare, you just need to be very careful, which most people aren't. The fact that companies publishing (or "leaking") results are biased also doesn't help much.

The common misconception is that you can compare a benchmark across two systems and get a single score for each. That ignores the fact that different systems have different optimization points, most often with regards to power (or "TDP"). What you need to look at is the power/performance curve - this graph shows how the system reacts to more power (raising the frequency, enabling more performance features, etc), and how much it contributes to its performance.
One system can win over the low power range, but lose when the available power increases since it doesn't scale that well (or even stops scaling at some point). This is usually the case with Arm, as most of these CPUs are tuned for low power, while x86 covers a larger domain and scales much better.

If you are forced to observe a single point along the graph (which is a legitimate scenario, for example if you're looking for a CPU for a low-power device), at least make sure the comparison is fair and uses the same power envelope.
There are of course other factors that must be aligned (and sometimes aren't due to negligence or an intention to cheat) - the workload should be the same (i've seen different versions compared..), the compiler should be as close as possible (although generating arm vs x86 code is already a difference, but the compiler intermediate optimizations should be similar. When comparing 2 x86 like intel and AMD you should prefer the same binary, unless you also want to allow machine specific optimizations).
Finally, the system should also be similar, which is not the case when comparing a smartphone against a pc/macbook. The memory could differ, the core count, etc. This could be  legitimate difference, but it's not really related to one architecture being better than the other.

Comment: People also get mixed up between existing implementations of an architecture, vs. the architecture (ISA) itself.  AArch64 is a nice ISA, and it's only economic / market (and design-time) factors stopping people from designing a really high-end high-power implementation with 4-wide or 6-wide out-of-order execution that could clock up to ~4GHz (like  Intel Kaby Lake or AMD Ryzen).  Just with a front-end that understands AArch64 instead of x86.  (And presumably it wouldn't need a decoded-uop cache because ARM is easy to decode).  Anyway, with 256b or 512b FMA 2-per-clock and all that.

Comment: (This was responding to your last sentence, about "one architecture being better".  It's microarchitectures that are the real issue, although the "x86 tax" (hard to decode and some crazy-CISC semantics on a few insns) does hurt x86 microarchitectures, even though x86 does give high code density.)

Comment: @PeterCordes, the last part was referring to difference between systems (e.g different DDR type, more memory channels, PCIe lanes) - these are architectural differences (in the sense of system design, not in the sense of specific implementation of this or that ISA), and you could argue that when comparing CPUs they are part of the difference, but in this context it's more interesting to compare cores (and microarchitecture)

Comment: Ah yes, agreed.  This http://pdadb.net/index.php?m=processor&id=718&c=apple_a11_bionic__t8015 claims that A11 has dual-channel "LPDDR4x" at 2064 MHz (i.e. DDR4-4128), for a theoretical bandwidth of 66.05 Gbyte/s.  That seems pretty fantastic (as in not really believable).  Although maybe with memory soldered in instead of socketed, they can clock it a lot higher than typical x86 desktops?

Answer (score 0):

the topic is bogus, from the ISA to an application or source code there are many abstraction level and the only metric that we have (execution time, or throughput) depends on many factors that could advantage one or the other: the algorithm choices, the optimization written in source code, the compiler/interpreter implementation/optimizations, the operating system behaviour. So they are not exactly/mathematically comparable.
However, looking at the numbers, and the **utility of the mobile application written** by talking as a management engeneer, ARM chip seems to be capable of run quite good.
I think the only reason is inertia of standard spread around (if you note microsoft propose a variant of windows running on ARM processors, debian ARM variant are ready https://www.debian.org/distrib/netinst).
the ARMv8 cores seems close to x86/64 ones by looking at raw numbers

- note i7-3770k results: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instructions_per_second#MIPS
- summary of last Armv8 CPU characteristics, note the quantity of decode, dispatch, caches, and compare the last column on cortex A73 to the i7 3770k
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_ARMv8-A_cores
- intel ivy bridge characteristics:
  https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/microarchitectures/ivy_bridge_(client)
- A75 details. https://www.anandtech.com/show/11441/dynamiq-and-arms-new-cpus-cortex-a75-a55

the topic of power consumption is complex again, the basic rule that go under all the frequency/tension rule (used and abused) over www is: transistors raise time. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rise_time

There is a fixed time delay in the switching of a transistor, this determinates the maximum frequency that a transistor could switch, and with more of them linked in a cascade way this time sums up in a nonlinear way (need some integration to demonstrate it), as a result 10 years ago to increase the GHz companies try to split in more stage the execution of an operation and runs them (operations) in a pipeline way, even inside the logical pipeline stage. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_pipelining

the raise time depends of physical characteristics (materials and shape of transistors). It can be reduced by increasing the voltage, so the transistor switch faster, as the switching is associated (let me the term) to a the charge/discharge of a capacitor that trigger the transistor channel opening/closing.

These ARM chips are designed to low power applications, by changing the design they could easily gain MHz, but they will use much power, how much? again not comparable if you don't work inside a foundry and have the numbers.

an example of server applications of ARM processors that could be closer to desktop/workstation CPU as power consumption are Cavium or qualcomm Falkor CPUs, and some benchmark report that they are not bad.

Comment: Please check [how to write an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That wikipedia table of ARMv8 uarches is interesting, but missing some key stuff like max MHz, and out-of-order window (ROB + scheduler) size.  The higher you clock a chip, the less you have time for in each pipeline stage.  So you need more stages, and need better branch predictors to avoid stalls.  Is the decode width always equal to the issue/rename width (Intel terminology: pipeline width for moving instructions from the front-end into the ROB + scheduler)?  For example, Skylake has 4-wide issue/rename, but (up to) 5-wide decode and (up to) 6-wide uop-cache fetch to hide front-end bubbles.

Comment: I add some detail that i remember to have seen during last months, from last samsung M3 custom design https://www.anandtech.com/show/12361/samsung-exynos-m3-architecture. I can't judge, cause they are not complete like how good is branch predictor, branch misprediction penaly, fma/simd operations,retire rate and so on? only report some numbers, even because they are not the same and always depends on algorithm and how is translated, there is no pareto optimality to say one is better than the other in all the use case. I made some trial using the same C++ source code but again is not the truth